# How prestashop crete new Order($id_order) function

Tags: php, object, prestashop

I'm trying to create my own new custom object for sale like `$order =new Order($id_order)` . I want to create like `$sale = new Sale($id_sale)`.

How can I do this in *adminOrderController.php* ?

Comment: There is no `Sale` class in PrestaShop. What is the purpose of `Sale`?

Comment: Do you require file with your Sale class into adminOrderController.php?